# Wildcard SSL certificate NGinx

Tags: nginx, ssl

I am getting an issue with NGinx where it is giving `error:05800074:x509 certificate routines::key values mismatch)`.

I have a Ubuntu Server (22.04 LTS) with NGinx (1.18.0) installed. I have a domain hosted on GoDaddy with cPanel etc (business plan) which has a WildCard SSL. I am trying to create x.domain.co.uk (x is placeholder for subdomain name in this post)

If you have worked with GoDaddy you know that when downloading the Certificates, it gives you `bundle.crt`, `certificate.pem` and `certificate.crt`.

I have tried using the `*.domain.co.uk` wildcard `.key` file with the `certificate.crt` as the 2 keys in the below NGinx config but it is showing a key mismatch.

I have also tried the sudo cat command to concat the `certificate.crt` with `bundle.crt` and using that file in place of the `certificate.crt` in the config but this shows the same error.

Here is my NGinx config file:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name x.domain.co.uk;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/certificates/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificates/certificate.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
    root /var/www/html/x/public;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    index index.htm index.html index.php;
    charset utf-8;
    autoindex on;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    error_page 404 /index.php;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Do I need to get the Private Key for the `x.domain.co.uk` rather than `*.domain.co.uk` (attempted above)? Where am I going wrong here?